# AngularJS Component define as function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-components

When i create a component with a function which is returning a **component** object, my component is not initialize! I am sharing these two situation. Can someone explain me what is the difference between them?

Html:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp">
  <navbar></navbar>
</div>
```

Working code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agL5zuzf/9/)

```
var NavbarTemplate = `<button ng-click="$ctrl.clickTest()">Click Test</button>`;
var navbar = {
  controller: function() {
    this.clickTest = clickTest;
    function clickTest() {
      alert("hello");
    }
  },
  template: NavbarTemplate
};
angular.module('demoApp', []).component('navbar', navbar);
```

Faulty (without error) code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agL5zuzf/8/)

```
function getComponent(){
    var template = `<button ng-click="$ctrl.clickTest()">Click Test</button>`;
    var component = {
    controller: function() {
      this.clickTest = clickTest;
      function clickTest() {
          alert("hello");
        }
    },
    template: template
  }
  return component;
}
angular.module('demoApp', []).component('navbar', getComponent);
```

Comment: aren't you supposed to pass it an object literal? try `.component('navbar', getComponent())`

Comment: @Daniel_L thank you for your answer. I tried it and it worked. I am familiar to work with directive :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to `getComponent` passed as a parameter to the last line like so:

`angular.module('demoApp', []).component('navbar', getComponent());`

Using simply `getComponent` (without parentheses) passes a reference to the `getComponent` function to `component()` without executing it. However, angular is expecting an object containing your component configuration.

Thus, passing `getComponent()` calls the function and returns the component configuration object passing said configuration object to angular `component()` initializer rather than a reference to the function `getComponent`.